# Microphone Picking up sound From Speaker in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I am working on video calling application in iPhone, have been able to video call till now, but facing an issue related to audio.The Person who is speaking is again able to hear his own voice,what actually happens is that the speaker sound at receiver end is being picked by the Microphone at receiver end and is sent again back to the transmitter and in this way the transmitter is able to hear his voice multiple times.

Consider I said hello the speaker at receiver end will produce hello sound and the Microphone will pick this up and will again send it back to me, when speaker at my end produce hello it is again captured by Microphone at my side and is sent back to the receiver and this occurs multiple times.How Can I get rid of this Issue. If I use Headset everything works fine.

Comment: looks like iPhone's hardware design issue :). Not really, i'm joking. Are you testing with devices side by side?

Comment: NO devices are far away from each other.

Comment: Which API you are using for video calls?

Comment: We have created our own custom API